# Can LED flood lights supplement north facing balcony light to grow tomatoes?

Tags: tomatoes, led

I have a north facing balcony that does not get enough light to grow most flowering plants or tomatoes.
I want to try supplementing with LED flood lights from behind. Is it worth the effort?

Comment: What you ask for is hard/expensive to achieve: http://ledgrowlightsoutlet.com/ledgrowlightscalculator.html